# STUN protocol: How to detect twice or double NAT firewalls?

Tags: firewall, nat, stun

[RFC 5780](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5780.txt) for STUN defines a Response-Origin attribute for STUN messages responses sent by the server back to the requesting client.

It describes it as:

> The RESPONSE-ORIGIN attribute is inserted by the server and indicates the source IP address and port the response was sent from.  It is useful for detecting double NAT configurations.  It is only present in Binding Responses.

How does the client use the server's source IP and port to detect double NAT configurations? Couldn't the source address information be just as easily read from the UDP packet's source field, seeing as inbound NAT only re-writes the destination address and not the source address?

Answer (score 0):

Server can tell two things:

i) What IP address it sees for you. If it does not match your ip address, you know there is a NAT between you and the server. You have been translated.

ii) What IP address it sees for the remote peer, and the IP address the remote peer communicated to the server. If they don't match, the remote peer is behind NAT too.

Hence, you can find whether you are dealing with a double-NAT situation.

Now this is not to be confused with situation where there are two NATs between you and the server for example. But in this case, you don't need to worry, because the server will work with the last NAT on your way from you to the server.

Comment: So if I'm hearing you correctly, you're saying that when RFC 5780 refers to double NAT, it is referring to for when your remote peer is also NAT. However, if that's correct, I'm also not seeing how the RESPONSE-ORIGIN attribute would be helpful for that. The spec defines the RESPONSE-ORIGIN as containing the STUN server's IP and port information, not that of a remote peer. How would this information be helpful in determining information about a remote peer?

Comment: Where do your read in RFC 5780 that RESPONSE-ORIGIN is the server's IP and port? What page? It only says that it inserts information of the respondent, not its own ip address and port.

Comment: In the line that I quoted from RFC 5780 it says RESPONSE-ORIGIN "is inserted by the server and indicates the source IP address and port the response was sent from". The response is going to be sent from the server's IP and port.

Comment: The response refers to the response from the target peer, not the server. The server reads the IP and port from the connection it has with the target, not its own IP and port. The fact that it is inserted by the server does not necessarily mean it is the server's IP and port address.